# Webpage content distorts when IE10 browser top menu bars are added.ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, html

My asp.net webpage looks good on IE 10 browser when no browser top menu,toolbars are added. But when I add IE10 top bars like favorites bar, command bar, status bar etc then my asp.net webpage goes down from its original position. And my elements inside the content area say like gridview gets distorted. So how do I adjust my webpage size even though the browser top bars are added?

Comment: is the height of your page fixed? how do you set it by the way?

Comment: my content height is 600px,header menu 110px,padding between content and header is 30px.footer is 66px and padding between content and footer is 30px. we have sticky footer.

Comment: You might have problem with other browsers to. I'd rather use height percentage for that.

Comment: is there any portal where we could get the exact percentage value for pixels?

Comment: Percentage depends on the actual height. For example you document is 600px then 100% of it is 600px, 50% of it is 300px, and so on.. If you use percentage instead of fixed px height, it will give you more dynamic styling.